# What should we focus while reading RFC document

Tags: rfc

I'm actually reading RFC documents on SMTP, URL's in the view of contributing to some programming library.

I just feel, things are not to the point and the adjectives are even referenced to their respective pages describing specifically. Being this specific for a policy making probably required but how a developer should get the exact point of what that entire paper is making quickly? Actually once I start reading one RFC, being newbie, within 5mins I see myself lost reading another RFC being referenced.

Any tips from guys who got experience is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The counter-question to that is **what are you trying to get out of reading RFCs?**  What level of understanding do you need to obtain?

RFCs are meant to be verbose enough that the reader can implement behaviour that conforms to the spec.  **The RFC is the spec.**  Reading the spec is always going to be very detailed and low level.

You would be better off searching for guides to the functionality that you need to understand and getting a **grasp of the basics** before diving into the RFC, in the same way that you might read the documentation for a program to understand what it's meant to do before you start reading the source code to figure out how it does it.